# PHP / HTML5 Contact Form - What is Wrong

Tags: php, html, contact-form, forms, http-post

I am just starting off with PHP and doing a few tutorials.  I have just built the following PHP contact form, but the PHP syntax in the header bleeds into the webpage and I am completely unsure why? It might be worth mentioning I have also saved this file as contactForm.php and not contactForm.html (does that make a difference).  What is wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Exercise: Contact Form</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/myStyle.css" />

    <?php
        $name = $_POST ['name'];
        $email = $_POST ['email'];
        $message = $_POST ['message'];
        $from = 'From: Me';
        $to = 'email@email.co.uk';
        $subject = 'Hello';
        $human = $_POST ['human'];

        $body = "From $name\n Email: $email\n Message: $message\n";

        if ($_POST ['submit'] && $human == '4') {
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<p>Something went wrong, please try again.</p>';
            }
        }
        else if ($_POST ['submit'] && $human != '4') {
                echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly.</p>';
            }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>My Test Page</h1>
    </header>

    <form id="testForm" method="post" action="contactForm.php">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input class="input-fields" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
        <label>E-mail:</label>
        <input class="input-fields" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <label>Message:</label>
        <textarea class="input-fields"  name="message" placeholder="Enter Message here" rows="5"></textarea>
        <label>What is 2 + 2?</label>
        <input class="input-fields" name="human" placeholder="Enter Answer">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Click to Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is the image of how it displays...

[image: screenshot of problem]

Comment: Are you running this on a server or opening the page locally in a browser?

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: Just in browser locally, just want to test the echo's to make sure they react to the form validation.

Comment: You need a server running PHP for the PHP to be processed. Opening the file locally won't do anything but produce the code in the page without being parsed.

Comment: Hi j08691, I understand this but surely the echo should still work without running the server side function. Also I have the php code starting from the first echo displayed on the Webpage, that is my only misunderstanding.

Comment: Nope, none of the PHP will run *at all* unless you have PHP running on a server.

Comment: php is compiled code. it needs a php compiler engine to compile it before it can be run. no browser has that

Comment: Ok thanks guys, appreciate the continued support :)

Comment: Hi Guys, image added of issue I am having!

Comment: PHP is a server side scripting language. The browser will only interpret HTML and JavaScript. I suggest looking at [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org) or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/‎) if you want to run a virtual apache server on your local machine.

Comment: Hi Rossco, but even without testing on a server surely there is an error in the script (see screenshot)?

Comment: Hi @Rossco, I have updated my question with an image of the problem, do you know what the issue could be?

Comment: Hi @j08691 I have updated my question with an image of the problem also would you know what the issue appears to be? Appreciate any comments

Comment: There will be no error. The browser will just interpret the php as plain text. I suggest using XAMPP or WAMP if you want to develop with php. It is impossible for a browser to interpret PHP code. PHP is a server side scripting language that is run on the server and as a result outputs HTML which the browser can understand

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP doesn't understand that you need a server to process PHP and it can't be run locally via the browser.

Comment: You were right all along guys, setup a server to run it and no script is bled into page! strange, but thank's so much guys. vote ups when I can.

Comment: @tom1bomb it is not `strange`. this is how it supposed to work. What strange is that someone is actually coding in php without knowing what PHP is . This is my new favorite question on SE !

Comment: I am still learning this @ObmerkKronen but thank you for the arrogant response.

Comment: @tom1bomb . It is not intended to be arrogant at all , sorry if it sounds like that . Actually, It reminded me to of my own first steps. But I must admit that it is quit strange that you managed to script that code above without ever realizing you need a server .

Comment: @ObmerkKronen I understand that PHP is server side, I (mistakenly) thought that even if the file is viewed locally the script wouldn't display like that. Hey ho, live and learn! Apology accepted. :)

Comment: I am sure that in one year time you will read this question and have a nice laugh. after all - you came to the best place on the net to learn.. I myself owe all of my ( humble and little ) knowledge to this site and it´s amazing people --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP must be run on a web server that has a php engine. It cannot be run directly in the browser from a file on your desktop.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.requirements.php